# std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher slower than the auto cx = data[i].find(pat)

Tags: c++17, boyer-moore

I am testing the text lines search speed for 1M lines.

I generate 1M vector string data , each has a text line .
pat is std::string search keyword.

c++ standard std::string.find 5 tees faster than the Boyer.

how it could be possible?

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin =
      std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  for (int i = 1; i <= val; ++i) {
    // std::cout << i << "  val:" << val << endl;
    // search(std::to_string(i) + fwtxt + std::to_string(i), pat);
    auto cx = data[i].find(pat); //!= std::string::npos)

    // auto it = std::search(data[i].begin(), data[i].end(),
    //                       std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher(pat.begin(),
    //                       pat.end()));

    // cout << cx << endl;           // std::cout << "found!" << '\n';

    // search(data[i], pat);
  }

  std::cout << ":: " << data[(rand() % 100)] << endl;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end =
      std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

  std::cout << "Time difference = "
            << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end -
                                                                     begin)
                   .count()
            << "[ms]" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Create `std::boyer_moore_horspool_searcher` for a given pattern once, then use the same instance for all searches. Boyer-Moore computes a data structure for the pattern that then speeds up looking for that pattern - this takes extra time, and only pays off if a) the same pattern is being searched for many times, so the data structure can be reused, or b) it's searched for once, but in a very large text, on the order of megabytes. Your current code constructs a new `boyer_moore_horspool_searcher` instance every time through the loop

Comment: @IgorTandetnik sounds like an answer

Comment: Further, even though the brute force search implemented by "string::find` is worst case `O(n*m)`, you are unlikely to actually hit this worst case with randomly generated strings. The worst case occurs when long prefixes, but not the full match, of the pattern occur frequently in the text; e.g. when searching for `aaaaa` in the text `aaaabaaaabaaaab...`. (continued)

Comment: In a typical case it's enough to check the first character or two of the pattern before moving along, and the brute force algorithm becomes `O(n)`. Boyer-Moore is `O(n+m)` even in the worst case - but you need a high change of actually encountering this worst case to justify the extra overhead of Boyer-Moore.